# More than 2 keywords search with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need only line (1) and (3) by the keyword "a" "b" and "c" by regular expression and javascript.

Text is:

> a+b+c (1)
>
> test+a+test (2)
>
> c+b+a(3)
>
> test+b+test (4)

I found "(?=.*a).*b". But how can I do with more than 2 keywords like the example?

Comment: How about `var a = string.split("+");`  Then access `a[0]` and a[2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *positive lookahead assertions* as in the following regex to match the required text:

```
/^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)/
```

More details about *lookahead* and *lookbehind* can be found here: [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

**JavaScript Demo**

```js
var a = "a+b+c";
var b = "test+a+test";
var c = "c+b+a";
var d = "test+b+test";

var pattern = /^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)/;

console.log(a + " ----- " + pattern.test(a));
console.log(b + " ----- " + pattern.test(b));
console.log(c + " ----- " + pattern.test(c));
console.log(d + " ----- " + pattern.test(d));
```

Comment: I think you have added incorrect fiddle link. Also its better to use stack snippet as it makes you answer independent.